# how to play video without html 5

Tags: jquery, video

i want to play uploaded videos on my web page, i found some jquery plugins but most of them are using html 5 such as  and `video-js-4.8.1` that is not supported in every browswer . 
but i want to play video without html 5 just like youtube

> is there any youtube like plugin to play video

i have also tried `<embed>` and `<object>` tags but i dont know how to add player in browser

Comment: Well...there's always Flash.

Comment: you can use **Microsoft Silverlight** too

Comment: There are various flash players out there. You can try http://www.jwplayer.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/)

> yet full-featured HTML5/Flash video player.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's never a good idea to play video hosted in your website. Video it's bandwidth hungry, and your video will be slow, jerky and you'll run out of bandwith very soon.

So, the best way is always to use a streaming service, and there is no cheaper streaming server than YouTube or Vimeo.

If even so you want to host the videos locally (in your server I mean), you'll need a Flash or Silverlight app

Comment: Do note that YouTube and Vimeo are blocked in some countries, so if the OP uses either of these sources he will be effectively decreasing views by around 30%

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how/why you want to use jquery to play video..
There are only two mainstream ways to play videos in a modern browser:

- HTML5 video
  `<video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>`
- Flash Player
  `<object width="400" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="helloworld.swf">`

But the best way would be to use both; HTML5 as the primary source and flash if HTML5 isn't supported.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <object width="400" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="helloworld.swf">    
</video>
```